# moving documents from firestore to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I have users documents stored in FireStore and would like to some how stream them into ElasticSearch index so that I can query for nearby users.

Currently, whenever the FireStore docs gets updated, I use cloud functions to make the change in ElasticSearch. However, I feel this will not scale and ElasticSearch might fail if there are a large number of documents that need to be updated in ElasticSearch..

I searched GCP for solutions and found out that I should use pub/sub and data flow.  As a matter of fact, data flow has a template to move logs from pub/sub to ElasticSearch.  I am not interested in moving logs to ElasticSearch.  I am interested in moving users documents to ElasticSearch index.  Does anyone know of a way to handle this.

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search?provider=elastic?

Comment: Given that a solution is documented, I recommend updating your question to show what you tried and how you determined that that approach isn't scalable enough for your use-case.

Comment: There's still not enough data here. Since somebody took the time to document that solution I linked and show code for it, I am inclined to assume it'll work. Instead of *feeling* that the solution doesn't scale, can you show us the data and code that proves that it doesn't?

Comment: Let us think a bit.  Suppose you have 100,000 users updating their profiles at once, how are you going to have enough cloud functions start at once and how are you going to write 100,000 documents individually to elasticsearch?